# Convert weekday to text output

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

In a monthly spreadsheet I have cells which contain the year (`A1`) Month (`A2`) and then the rest of the column running from cell `A4` through to `A34` numbered as the day in the Month (1 to 31).

My objective is to place the correct day of the week (in text) besides the day of the month (number).

So far I have successfully used the following formulae individually -

`=(DATE(A1;A2;A5))` in this case returning `02/10/2020`
`=CHOOSE(A4;"Mon";"Tue";"Wed";"Thu";"Fri";"Sat";"Sun")` returning Mon (`A4=1`)
`=WEEKDAY(DATE(A1;A2;A5);2)` which gives 5 indicating Friday (correct for `02/10/20`)
`=DAY(DATE(A1;A2;A5))`

`WEEKDAY(date())` returns the number of the day and parameter 2 indicates that the week begins on Monday.

The date format required is the English version `DD/MM/YY`

What I now need to do is to somehow combine these formulae to copy down in cells B4 to B34 in order to place the correct day of the week against the day number in respect of that month but this so far eludes me.

A suggested working formula would be much appreciated.

The references I have used:

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092969?hl=en&ref_topic=3105385
https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093371?hl=en
https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092985?hl=en
https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093040?hl=en

Interestingly, all these references suggest comma delimiters rather than semicolons between the formula elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use a formula, this could be achieved by using cell format. Click Format > Number > More formats > Custom number formats then use `dddd d`

- `dddd` for the day of the week.
- `d` for the day of the month (1,2, etc. or `dd` for 01, 02, etc.)

Comment: So, I still have to use the formula to construct the date in the cell as =(DATE($A$1;$A$2;$A5)) then formatting the cell as per your answer works a treat. (using only dddd in this case). Thanks very much! Another problem solved.